# Unable to read cookie sent from React js frontend on Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

In my React js front end, I am setting a cookie with [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie).
I have verified that the request cookie is correctly being set:

[image: cookie is being set in Request header]

On the Express server, I have set up the [cookie parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html)

```
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/instruments', function (req, res) {
  // Cookies that have not been signed
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)

  // Cookies that have been signed
  console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.signedCookies)
})
```

[image: Unable to read the cookie on express server]

As we can see, the cookie is invisible on the server. Why is that so?

Comment: Check your React part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working correctly

`access-token=%7B%7D` url decodes to `access-token={}`

Which is what is being logged in your terminal

It seems like however you are using `react-cookie` to send the cookie value part is the problem not the transmission or server